# angularjs set checkbox checked using expression

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to set checked = "checked" for a checkbox inside a ng-repeat

My current code is :

```
<tr ng-repeat="current in listobjects" on-list-displayed>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "status" value="1" {{ current.status > 0 ? ' checked="checked"' : '' }}>
</tr>
```

But

```
{{ current.status > 0 ? ' checked="checked" : "" }}
```

is not parsed by angularjs and displayed as text

What's wrong ?

Comment: Try to use `ng-checked`. E.g. `ng-checked="current.status > 0"`

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-checked for this

```
<tr ng-repeat="current in listobjects" on-list-displayed>
    <input type="checkbox" name = "status" value="1" ng-checked="current.status > 0">
</tr>
```